# About a man and a bee

Tags: riddle, wordplay, humor

A man walks out of his house and over to his flower garden. He holds out his right hand and a bee lands in it.

**What is in his eye?**

Comment: ask an ophthalmologists, he will say (retina,iris, cornea, etc) .

Comment: Hello Kevin, that's a fun question. Can I add this puzzle to my website, will post it under your name?

Comment: Artur, Yes of course. To give credit where it's due, I heard this from my friend Tanner. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

> Beauty

Because:

> "Beauty is in the eye of the beholder (bee holder)"

Comment: HAAAAAA. HA. Ha.... ha..... funny....

Comment: Great ans...(y)